# Feature selection with information gain (KL divergence) and mutual information yields different results

Tags: feature-selection, ranking, information-theory, mutual-information

I'm comparing different techniques for feature selection / feature ranking. Two of the techniques under scrutiny are the mutual information (MI) and the information gain (IG) as used in decision trees, i.e. the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

My data (class and features) is all binary.

All sources I could find state, that MI and IG are basically "two sides of the same coin", i.e. that one can be tranformed into the oher via mathematical manipulation. (For example [[source 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674116/mutual-information-vs-information-gain), [source 2]](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/cs769/info.pdf))

Yet, when I rank my features using the two measures they **do not result in the same ranking** order. But if the two measures are equivalent, shouldn't the ranking be the same?

Can someone help me understand why the rankings are different?

Comment: Can you find a documentation to be ensured that the software/library is naming its implementation correctly? Also, you can use a simple calculable example to see if its naming is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remind that $I[X;Y]$ is symmetrical, but $KL(P \Vert Q)$ is not. $I[X;Y] = KL(P(X,Y)\Vert P(X)P(Y))$.  Take a look if you are not computing $KL(P(X)\Vert P(Y))$.